# program.cs accidently 'saved as' in different folder -> visual studio couldnt find it (0x80070003)

Tags: visual-studio

as I said in the title, I saved my program.cs in another directory.
The original program.cs file is still in my project directory.

If I open the oringinal in my VS it shows up and the matching project aswell, but whenever i manually click on my program.cs class in the VS it says that it couldnt find the path - and the path where it looks up for it is the path of the moved program.cs.

But I want to point at the original program.cs, inside of the project directory.
So do you know how I can show it to the VS and tell it which path to use?

Hopefully I could explain my problem... :)

I tried to change it in the propertiers but couldnt find an option. Rebuilding in the hope that it uses its default path didnt worked aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to point at the original program.cs, inside of the project
> directory. So do you know how I can show it to the VS and tell it
> which path to use?

If you delete the wrong cs file, and then right click on your project and select "Add", there's an "Add existing item", which will let you browse for the one you want to use.